# Geodesic through/between singularities

Tags: differential-geometry, analyticity, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb R^q$ be a (singular) real algebraic set, and
 let
 $$
 g\colon[0,T]\to X
 $$
 be a geodesic
 (that is, a shortest path between its ends).
 Is it true that
 the image $g([0,T])$ is contained in
 some (possibly singular) analytic curve?
 By an analytic curve I mean a 1-dimensional analytic subset
 of an open set in $X$.

Comment: I don't know the answer but do you know if it's true for $X$ smooth ?

Comment: I am almost sure that this is true if $X$ is smooth. Analyticity is a local property. Dense geodesic on a torus is not our case, because a geodesic in our sense is compact. The natural parametrization of a geodesic in the smooth case is an analytic map, because it satisfies a differential equation with analytic coefficients. The image of an analytic immersion locally is an analytic set (I believe).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the precisions. Sorry for the naive suggestion, but why not take a resolution of singularities $Y \to X$, take the strict transform of $g([0,T])$ which is contained in an analytic curve and project such analytic curve ? Won't this give you a (possibly singular) analytic curve containing your geodesic ?

Comment: It is not clear whether that strict transform is contained in an analytic curve. Do you think it is a geodesic? I guess no.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the answer is yes.

Geodesic curves $g:[0,T] \rightarrow X$ are solution of the differential equation 
$$
\frac{d^2 g^{(i)}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{i}_{j,k} \frac{d g^{(j)}}{ds}\frac{d g^{(k)}}{ds}=0 \quad i,j,k=1,\cdots, m
$$
where the coeffients $\Gamma^{i}_{j,k}$ dependent on the regulary of the manifold. The analyticity of $g$ depends on analyticity of $\Gamma^{i}_{j,k}$.

Moreover in the book "Algebraic Geometry" of Hartshorne, there is a proof that every non-singular algebraic variety is an analytical manifold. Hence $X$ is an analytical manifold in almost everywhere. Thus your geodesic curve is an analytic curve with possibly isolate non-smooth points.

Comment: You do not answer my question. I asked whether a geodesic can have "non-analytic" singularities similar to the singularity of the curve $y=x\sin(1/x)$ at the origin (the origin is assumed to be included in the curve).